# slide out after pressing a button

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Is it possible to make table cell slide out to the left after pressing a button (three vertical dots icon)?

Here's an image:

[image]

Comment: http://t1p.de/uu43

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the method:
`func deleteRowsAtIndexPaths(_ indexPaths: [NSIndexPath], withRowAnimation animation: UITableViewRowAnimation)`

Probably animation that you are looking for is `UITableViewRowAnimation.Left`

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that with this:

```
tableView.beginUpdates

//Add code to update your dataModel

tableView.deleteSections(NSIndexSet(index: indexPathOfRemovedCell.section), withRowAnimation: .Left)

tableView.endUpdates()
```

Answer (score 0):

To make table cell slide out to the left after pressing a button (three vertical dots icon), you can set the editing to true as below:-

```
tableView.setEditing(true, animated: true)
```

This will load the table in edit mode. Edit mode means showing the red minus symbol on the left hand side. Clicking on it, will show the delete button.

Answer (score 0):

You can do try setting the cell.contentView's frame's origin x to "current value-buttonWidth" and on another tap you can set it to original one.